# Update row value based on condition in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a bridge between 2 financial systems (not schoolwork) and I've hit a wall.

Here's my sample dataframe at this point (numbers are made up):

```
data = {'Receipt #': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-06'],
        'Debit' : [10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0, 0, 13, 22],
        'Credit': [0, 0, 10, 5, 30, 10, 0, 0, 22, 13, 0, 0],
        'Restriction': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

I've gotten the dataframe to this point, which is almost where I need it, but I'm stuck with the restrictions column.

Each group of transactions has the same receipt number with:

- the count of positive credit values equaling the count of positive debit values
- the sum of debit equals the sum of credit

My problem is the 'Restriction' column.  Within each receipt number (group), the restriction codes for rows that have a positive Debit value need to be the same as the rows that have a positive Credit value.

In the example above, restrictions should look like this:

```py
[2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]
```

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Receipt #": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "Date": [
        "2023-01-01",
        "2023-01-01",
        "2023-01-01",
        "2023-01-01",
        "2023-01-04",
        "2023-01-04",
        "2023-01-04",
        "2023-01-04",
        "2023-01-06",
        "2023-01-06",
        "2023-01-06",
        "2023-01-06",
    ],
    "Debit": [5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 10, 0, 0, 13, 22],
    "Credit": [0, 0, 10, 5, 30, 10, 0, 0, 22, 13, 0, 0],
    "Restriction": [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Iterate through unique 'Receipt #' values
for receipt_num in df["Receipt #"].unique():
    # Identify rows with the current 'Receipt #'
    subset_df = df[df["Receipt #"] == receipt_num]

    # Identify rows where 'Credit' has the same value as 'Debit'
    same_value_rows = subset_df[subset_df["Credit"] == subset_df["Debit"]]

    # Update 'Restriction' in rows where 'Credit' is 0 to match 'Debit' rows
    df.loc[
        same_value_rows[same_value_rows["Credit"] == 0].index, "Restriction"
    ] = same_value_rows.loc[same_value_rows["Debit"] == 0, "Restriction"].values

# Save the modified DataFrame to a new CSV file
df.to_csv(path_or_buf="output.csv", index=False)

print("Modified rows saved to output.csv:")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
 Receipt #        Date  Debit  Credit  Restriction
0           1  2023-01-01      5       0            1
1           1  2023-01-01     10       0            1
2           1  2023-01-01      0      10            2
3           1  2023-01-01      0       5            1
4           2  2023-01-04      0      30            2
5           2  2023-01-04      0      10            2
6           2  2023-01-04     30       0            1
7           2  2023-01-04     10       0            1
8           3  2023-01-06      0      22            1
9           3  2023-01-06      0      13            1
10          3  2023-01-06     13       0            1
11          3  2023-01-06     22       0            1
```

I apologize if my formatting is off, this is my first stack overflow post.

Here is an example of the output of the whole df:

Receipt #,Date,Customer #,Description,Fund,Effective Date,Debit,Credit,GLCode,Dept,Program,Activity,SubActivity,Funding,Restriction
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,0,45.36,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,0,61.19,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,45.36,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,61.19,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,0,135.04,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,0,0.18,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,135.04,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,0.18,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,0,358.11,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,0,455.94,23200,12,16,90,0,0,2
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,0,760.6,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,358.11,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,455.94,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,760.6,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,0,46.19,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,0,62.13,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,46.19,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,62.13,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,0,168.32,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,0,196.68,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,168.32,0,114,12,16,70,0,0,1
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,196.68,0,114,12,16,70,0,0,1
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,0,117.63,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,0,143.03,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,117.63,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,143.03,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1

Here is an example of the output I need:

Receipt #,Date,Customer #,Description,Fund,Effective Date,Debit,Credit,GLCode,Dept,Program,Activity,SubActivity,Funding,Restriction
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,0,45.36,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,0,61.19,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,45.36,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,2
1,1/10/2024,Bob,Loan: 1,16,1/2/2024,61.19,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,0,135.04,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,0,0.18,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,135.04,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,2
2,1/10/2024,Jill,Loan: 2,16,1/2/2024,0.18,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,0,358.11,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,0,455.94,23200,12,16,90,0,0,2
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,0,760.6,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,358.11,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,2
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,455.94,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,2
3,1/10/2024,Sam,Loan: 3 ,16,1/2/2024,760.6,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,0,46.19,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,0,62.13,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,46.19,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,2
4,1/10/2024,Lu,Loan: 4,16,1/2/2024,62.13,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,0,168.32,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,0,196.68,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,168.32,0,114,12,16,70,0,0,2
5,1/10/2024,Don,Loan: 5,16,1/2/2024,196.68,0,114,12,16,70,0,0,1
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,0,117.63,193,12,16,70,0,0,2
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,0,143.03,471,12,16,70,0,0,1
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,117.63,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,2
6,1/10/2024,Sara,Loan: 6,16,1/2/2024,143.03,0,113,12,16,70,0,0,1

To answer the question about restriction 1 vs 2, some fund codes are restriction 1 and some are restriction 2 (for some, GLCode determines the restriction code and for others Program determines the restriction code).

In my df, a given GLCode that starts with 11 is a cash account and will always be a debit.  The other GLCodes stand for various accounts with credits.

So for receipt 1 the first line has GLCode 193 and a credit of 45.36.  The restriction code on this line is 2.  Line 3 has a debit of 45.36 and is related to line 1 (credit and debit balances).  Line 3 should have a restriction code of 2.

Does this help clarify what I'm trying to do.  Thank you all for looking at this.

Comment: please improve the formatting of your post

Comment: can you also share your expected output df? I am having hard time understanding the problem part

Comment: Please edit the question explaining why the first Receipt # group should have Restriction values `[2, 1, 2, 1]`.

Comment: I believe there is an error, the output should be `[1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]` (first two values swapped)

Comment: @TinoD, I'm not sure what you're asking.  While, I've read a lot on stack overflow, this is the first time I've reached out for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can filter the positive Credit values, rename the column as Debit and perform a self left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
m = df['Credit'].gt(0)
df['Restriction_new'] = (
 df[['Receipt #', 'Date', 'Debit']]
 .merge(df.loc[m, ['Receipt #', 'Date', 'Credit', 'Restriction']]
          .drop_duplicates(subset=['Receipt #', 'Date', 'Credit'])
          .rename(columns={'Credit': 'Debit'}),
        how='left')
 ['Restriction'].fillna(df['Restriction']).astype(int) 
)
```

If you can have several time the same number in Credit/Debit (e.g. two times `10`) and want to perform a match in order, further add a deduplication key to the merge:

```
m = df['Credit'].gt(0)
Dn = df.groupby(['Receipt #', 'Debit']).cumcount()
Cn = df.groupby(['Receipt #', 'Credit']).cumcount()

df['Restriction_new'] = (
 df[['Receipt #', 'Date', 'Debit']].assign(n=Dn)
 .merge(df.loc[m, ['Receipt #', 'Date', 'Credit', 'Restriction']]
          .rename(columns={'Credit': 'Debit'})
          .assign(n=Cn[m]),
        how='left')
 ['Restriction'].fillna(df['Restriction']).astype(int) 
)
```

Output (as a new column for clarity):

```
    Receipt #        Date  Debit  Credit  Restriction  Restriction_new
0           1  2023-01-01      5       0            1                1
1           1  2023-01-01     10       0            1                2
2           1  2023-01-01      0      10            2                2
3           1  2023-01-01      0       5            1                1
4           2  2023-01-04      0      30            2                2
5           2  2023-01-04      0      10            2                2
6           2  2023-01-04     30       0            1                2
7           2  2023-01-04     10       0            1                2
8           3  2023-01-06      0      22            1                1
9           3  2023-01-06      0      13            1                1
10          3  2023-01-06     13       0            1                1
11          3  2023-01-06     22       0            1                1
```